# Maven compilation error for android Project "error: package R does not exist "

Tags: java, android, maven

I am trying to set up a MAVEN project with Android application.
I have this pom file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>userprofile</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>userprofile</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and during MAVEN compile I get this error (about 100 times, ie as many times as it is used in my methods)

```
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
src\main\java\com\myproject\userprofile\BaseActivity.java:[52,43] error: package R does not exist
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea about this error? On the web I either find unanswered questions about similar error output. I have no experience on MAVEN, so I believe I am missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R class is build by your IDE during compilation. MAVEN cannot find the R class because by default the class can be found under build folder. You need to add something like this

```
<sourceDirectory>build</sourceDirectory>
<outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
```

telling MAVEN that you have some resource files under build folder and you want to make them available to compile so add them under the target folder which will be under your project.

so now I have

```
build
  |----res
  |----src
src
  |----main
       |----java
       |----res 
target
```

Answer (score 0):

After a quick look, I believe you're missing the `build` element. Maven is building the project with current sources, `R` and other `gen` classes have not been generated yet. At least you need something like (after `dependencies` tag):

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <!-- platform or api level (api level 16 = platform 4.1)-->
                    <platform>16</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also the packaging must be `apk`:

```
<packaging>apk</packaging>
```

I would strongly recommend to start reading the [Android Maven documentation](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted) along with [samples](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples).

Comment: whenever I change the package to apk I get the error Unknown packaging: apklib @ line 6, column 14

Comment: that' because you need to have installed this jayway plugin. Have a look at the links I have provided on how to install this Android maven plugin

Comment: is this jayway plugin available only for eclipse? I use Android Studio and I cannot find a way to install this plugin for AS. Thanx again!

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue? Did you manage to install jayway? And can it build from command line? like: `mvn clean install`

Comment: No because I dont really get it with this jayway. How do i install it. From command line when I run mvn clean install I still get the error: package R does not exist

Comment: From the links I gave you, you should have [this link](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-config-build.html#android-dev-sect-repository-install). It's in the `Getting Started` - the first link.

Comment: The problem is that MAVEN could not find the R class which is under build folder outside of the src folder. So I had to deal with <sourceDirectory> and <outputDirectory> tags inside the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

This error might happen if you had modify the package name that generate by **archetype:generate**, for me, I use android-quickstart to generate the module structure :

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.11 \
    -DgroupId=com.yy.android.gameLibs \
    -DartifactId=sample
```

akquient recommend me to use "com.yy.android.gameLibs" as package name and I accepted, I compile this module successful and worked. After that, I change the package name as "com.yy.android.sample" also change the Androidmenifest.xml package attribute, therefore the module report that error, I follow back the generate command and choice package name myself to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Modify packaging to apklib, like this:

```
<packaging>apklib</packaging>
```

And add build goal at end of pom.xml like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <!--Android deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>        
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <platform>17</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```